# C# Syntax Issue

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following C# code:

```
private bool MailBoxAlreadyExists(string userEmail, Runspace runSpace)
{
    Pipeline pipeLine = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
    Command createMailBox = new Command("Get-User");
    createMailBox.Parameters.Add("identity", userEmail);
    pipeLine.Commands.Add(createMailBox);
    Collection user = pipeLine.Invoke();
    PSMemberInfo item = user[0].Properties.Where(property => property.Name == "RecipientType").SingleOrDefault();
    if (item != null)
    {
        if (string.Equals(item.Value.ToString(), "UserMailbox", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            pipeLine.Dispose();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            pipeLine.Dispose();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Im looking at the `PSMemberInfo item = user[0].Properties.Where(property => property.Name == "RecipientType").SingleOrDefault();` line of code. Im not exactly sure what is going on in the `Where(property => property.Name == "RecipientType")` part of the statement. I think this is some type of lambda expression or something. Could someone explain this?

Second part of the question is, this code is underlined in Visual Studio. I get the following error from it:

```
Error   2   'System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfoCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfoCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\dvargo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DVLib\ActiveDirectory\ADRunner.cs 566 33  ActiveDirectory
```

So to preform this kind of operation do I need another Assembly reference?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>This is Lambda expression indeed, which is part of [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx).</strike>

The `Where` method is is part of [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx), not Lambda expression by itself.

To be able to use it, add such line on top of your page:

```
using System.Linq;
```

You need the machine to have .NET 3.5 or higher installed, and the project in Visual Studio to target that framework or higher as well.

Comment: No, lambda expressions aren't part of LINQ. They're part of C# 3, and they're heavily *used* in LINQ, but you can still use them when targeting .NET 2.0 which doesn't have LINQ. The `Where` method is part of LINQ, but that's a different matter.

Comment: @gbianchi - LINQ was added in .NET 3.5 as far as I know, you say the extension methods were added just in .NET 4.0?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Lambda statements are not available in .NET 2.0 (unless there was a service pack). Anonymous delegates, which are roughly synonymous but have a different syntax, may be. However, you are correct that lambdas and LINQ are two different concepts; LINQ makes use of lambdas, but you do not have to use the System.Linq library just to use lambdas; it's just a syntax thing.

Comment: @Jon thanks, please see my edit and correct me if still wrong.

Comment: @KeithS correct but `Where` is extension method included in the `System.Linq` as far as I can tell that's why it's required.

Comment: @KeithS: Lambda *expressions*, not lambda *statements*. And yes, you definitely *can* use lambda expressions when targeting .NET 2. I do it all the time. You can't use them when *building* with .NET 2, because they're a C# 3 language feature - but you can build with a C# 3 compiler and target .NET 2. Many of the C# 3 features (anonymous types, `var`, better type inference for generic methods etc) work fine against .NET 2.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: It's now correct, but doesn't really address the question of what the `=>` syntax is - it's a lambda expression.

Comment: This is true. Just making a point that the two concepts are separable and you can use lambdas without Linq, but Linq needs lambdas.

Comment: @KeithS: I agree with that point, which is why I'd made it 5 minutes later. But what better way to demonstrate that separation than to point out that you can use lambda expressions on platform where LINQ isn't even supported? :)

Answer (score 3):

`.Where` and `.SingleOrDefault` are both in the `System.Linq` namespace, so you will have to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of the file.

In C#, the `=>` operator denotes a lambda expression. A lambda is fairly simple to understand: it is an anonymous function, so the lambda

```
property => property.Name == "RecipientType"
```

is a function that takes an (implicitly typed) parameter `property` and returns the boolean expression `property.Name == "RecipientType"`. A function that takes an object and returns a boolean is also known as a predicate.

Answer (score 2):

The `=>` part is a [*lambda expression*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). A lambda expression can be converted into a *delegate* or an [*expression tree*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx). It's like a better version of anonymous methods which were introduced in C# 2.

The `Where` method is part of LINQ. In this case you *probably* mean the LINQ to Objects version, [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) - but it's not entirely clear as we don't know about the types involved. I strongly recommend that you start learning LINQ from a book or good tutorial - it isn't really the kind of topic which can be learned easily from a Q&A site such as Stack Overflow.

Your error is probably due to one of three problems:

- You may not be using .NET 3.5, which is a pre-requisite for LINQ unless you use a third party library such as LINQBridge.
- You may not have a using directive of `using System.Linq;` in your code
- `PSMemberInfoCollection` may not implement the generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface. We can't really tell that part from what you've presented.

If you can give us more information, we may be able to help more.